# samplerate conversion function fails to produce an audible sound but only small pieces of audio

Tags: c, audio, ffmpeg, signal-processing

playmp3() using libmpg123

```
if (isPaused==0 && mpg123_read(mh, buffer, buffer_size, &done) == MPG123_OK)
{
    char * resBuffer=&buffer[0]; //22100=0,5s
    buffer = resample(resBuffer,22050,22050); // I think the result is 1/2 of audio speed
    if((ao_play(dev, (char*)buffer, done)==0)){
        return 1;
}
```

resample() Using avcodec from ffmpeg

```
#define LENGTH_MS 500       // how many milliseconds of speech to store 0,5s:x=1:44100 x=22050 sample to store
#define RATE 44100      // the sampling rate (input)
#define FORMAT PA_SAMPLE_S16NE  // sample size: 8 or 16 bits
#define CHANNELS 2      // 1 = mono 2 = stereo

struct AVResampleContext* audio_cntx = 0;
//(LENGTH_MS*RATE*16*CHANNELS)/8000

    void resample(char in_buffer[],int out_rate,int nsamples,char out_buffer[])
    {
        //char out_buffer[ sizeof( in_buffer ) * 4];
        audio_cntx = av_resample_init( out_rate, //out rate
            RATE, //in rate
            16, //filter length
            10, //phase count
            0, //linear FIR filter
            1.0 ); //cutoff frequency
        assert( audio_cntx && "Failed to create resampling context!");
        int samples_consumed;
        //*out_buffer = malloc(sizeof(in_buffer));
        int samples_output = av_resample( audio_cntx, //resample context
            (short*)out_buffer, //buffout
            (short*)in_buffer,  //buffin
            &samples_consumed,  //&consumed
            nsamples,       //nb_samples
            sizeof(out_buffer)/2,//lenout sizeof(out_buffer)/2
            0);//is_last
        assert( samples_output > 0 && "Error calling av_resample()!" );
        av_resample_close( audio_cntx );    
    }
```

When I run this code, the application part, the problem is that I hear the sound jerky, why? 
The size of the array I think is right, I calculated considering that in the second half should be 22050 samples from store.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but you may be failing to meet real time requirements. As in, the kernel may not be giving your application enough CPU time to do the processing it needs. If you're running in linux try decreasing application niceness, and if that fails try setting priority to SCHED_FIFO with high priority.  You may need to adjust the system priority limit via ulimit to get this to work.

Comment: how is this possible? In theory, the program is very small and this is the only function that changes the sound. Plus my computer is a i7 quadcoreda 3 GHz, the goal is to run my program on this raspberry, so I do not think this solution is applicable :/